# ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownList query via string won't return anything

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have WinForms application that has `MenuStrip` with single item `ToolStripMenuItem menuItem`, that were added via MSVC's designer.

In code, I am adding new item to `menuItem` and then I am trying to find it in it's `DropDownItems` collection. I've tried several ways, but none can successfully find recently added item.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string name = "Name";
    var nameItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(name);
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(name);
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(nameItem);

    // query via string doesn't work
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems[name] != null); // fails
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems.ContainsKey(name)); // fails
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems.Find(name, false).Length > 0); // fails
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems.IndexOfKey(name) >= 0); // fails

    // query via reference does
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems.Contains(nameItem)); // passes
    Debug.Assert(menuItem.DropDownItems.IndexOf(nameItem) >= 0); // passes
}
```

Comment: What you supply is the text of the item, not its name.  How about this:  `menuItem.DropDownItems.Add("text to display").Name = name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Add()`, you can either pass in the text to be displayed, or the item itself.  It's why your first set of tests fails and the second set works.

When you use `menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(name)`, you have not named it, therefore your attempts to find by name fail.

When you use `menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(nameItem)`, you have added the actual item, and that item *was* given a name.